# rails 3.0.1 dynamic asset generation pre/post capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, assets, asset-pipeline, unicorn

I am running rails 3.0.1, and while we intend to move to 3.1 and the asset pipeline I am looking for solutions/workarounds for asset generation during unicorn hot restarts.

Essentially what happens currently is we deploy to our site and when the deploy is complete the "current" symlink is changed to the new directory which does not have the static assets yet.  Then approximately 60 seconds later all assets are generated and all is well, but for the 60 seconds before the assets are generated our site is basically down.

Questions:

1. If I copy the files from the old release dir, to the new dir will the asset generation overwrite the older files I've copied?
2. Where in the rails code is the asset generation done?  ActionPack Dispatcher?
3. Is the generation of these assets done upon initialization of the app or at another stage?

Answer (score 0):

If you layout is something like this:

```
/srv/yourapplication/current
```

You should have a shared folder

```
/srv/yourapplication/shared/assets
```

and symlink public/assets to /srv/yourapplication/shared/assets

This way each time your old assets and new assets will all be in the same folder and will be served properly.

Comment: I think that is correct if you are using the asset pipeline.  To confirm I am not using the asset pipeline and am looking for an answer to the above questions

Comment: Where are you currently storing your assets? Anything you store in /public won't be modified by the asset pipeline and should work exactly as it does now.

Comment: ive posted my workaround here but am still after answers to the questions: http://petey5king.github.com/2011/12/10/rails-asset-pipeline-hack.html